# Page template - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: kentico

I have a page template that has this line of code below:

```
<div id="<%= CurrentDocument.NodeAlias %>" class="lvl3">
```

Things work - the id value shows correctly. However, when using the **Page Templates** module **Design tab**, there's an error. In Event log, I saw the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Taking the id snippet out, the error is gone. I'm not sure what the error means and how to fix it. Could you help?

I do need some page-specific unique identifier in there (NodeAlias in this case) for other purposes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using code blocks on page template layout is not supported. I assume you are using ASCX layout.  Moreover your code looks more like a macro - so, maybe you are using HTML [layout type](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-portal-engine/editing-page-layouts)? If yes, then the syntax should be `{%CurrentDocument.NodeAlias%}`
If you are using ASCX layout you may face also this issue: https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks
Note that in portal engine the life cycle is bit modified, so we cannot ensure the code blocks will work every time - it may work sometimes. It mainly depends on what other web parts/controls and in what order are placed in the page template. I would rather recommend using the workaround from the article. 
Or, you can give it a try, with no guarantee, this may work in certain cases, you need to specify the full namespace:

```
<%= CMS.MacroEngine.MacroResolver.Resolve("{%CurrentDocument.NodeAlias#%}") %>
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty simple - if you open your page template in Kentico Page Templates application - your CurrentDocument is always null (because you are editing Template itself without specific document).

You could do absolutely the same thing in Pages application with the Design tab. It's also possible to edit all the template properties from there, including the Layout:

[image: pages application]

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I'm aware of this. Just wanted for the template to be without error in both the Pages and the Page Templates applications.